# Is it possible to combine two rows column values into one row based on sku_id in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have written a query to check for certain values corresponding to sku_id 10005011 and to create flag columns based on those values...Now I have duplicate rows ...how can I combine those row values into one row...[Refer to the Output snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiqf8.png)
This is how each sku_id is set in the table[Snapshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP0Ph.png)

```
select pf.sku_id,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Alcohol' 
            then 1 
        else 0
        end) as Alcohol,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Egg_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Egg_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Dairy_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Dairy_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Fish' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Fish,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Gluten_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Gluten_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Lactose_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Lactose_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Meat' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Meat,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Milk_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Milk_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Nut_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Nut_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Organic' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Organic,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Peanut_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Peanut_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Soya_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Soya_Free,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Vegan' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Vegan,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Vegeterian' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Vegeterian,
    (case 
        when  f.Name='Wheat_Free' 
            then 1
        else 0
        end) as Wheat_Free
from orl-tst-inf-dpf-prj01.DataPlatform_Edw_Product.Product_Flag as pf, UNNEST(Flag) as f
where f.Is_True=true
order by pf.sku_id;
```

Comment: Are the Flags.Name values always constant as we can see in snapshot ?

Comment: Yes, they will remain same whether the flag is enabled or not

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to keep all the 1s that you find for the various subflags -- which you could accomplish by using max, and then group by.

See if this works for you:

```
    with base as (
      select pf.sku_id,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Alcohol' 
              then 1 
          else 0
          end) as Alcohol,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Egg_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Egg_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Dairy_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Dairy_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Fish' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Fish,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Gluten_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Gluten_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Lactose_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Lactose_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Meat' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Meat,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Milk_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Milk_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Nut_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Nut_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Organic' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Organic,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Peanut_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Peanut_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Soya_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Soya_Free,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Vegan' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Vegan,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Vegeterian' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Vegeterian,
      (case 
          when  f.Name='Wheat_Free' 
              then 1
          else 0
          end) as Wheat_Free
  from orl-tst-inf-dpf-prj01.DataPlatform_Edw_Product.Product_Flag as pf, UNNEST(Flag) as f
  where f.Is_True=true
)
select sku_id, max(Alcohol) as Alcohol, max(Egg_Free) as Egg_Free
from base
group by sku_id
order by sku_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
select pf.sku_id,*
    
from orl-tst-inf-dpf-prj01.DataPlatform_Edw_Product.Product_Flag as pf, UNNEST(Flag) as f
pivot(max(case when f.Is_True = 'TRUE' then 1 else 0 end) for f.name 
    in ('Alcohol','Egg_Free','Dairy_Free','Fish','Gluten_Free' ,'Lactose_Free' ,'Meat','Milk_Free','Nut_Free' ,'Organic' ,'Peanut_Free' ,'Soya_Free' ,'Vegan' ,'Vegeterian' ,'Wheat_Free'))
order by pf.sku_id;
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work

Comment: Any error specifically ?

Comment: This is resulting in the entire table orl-tst-inf-dpf-prj01.DataPlatform_Edw_Product.Product_Flag data.